# Particle at Input.mousePosition Point

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to understand [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html) link which, I believe, is supposed to create a particle where you left-click your mouse. Am I correct?

I have attached the script to an empty game object, so it runs when I run my Unity project. I added a new `Particle System` game object and dragged it onto the public field of the inspector. Is this the right way of doing it, or should I assign something else to the public variable?

The particle system starts firing up as soon as I run the project, so how do I stop that and then make it begin when and where I have clicked my mouse curser?

```
public GameObject particle;

if ( Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") )
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    if ( Physics.Raycast(ray) )
        Instantiate(particle, transform.position, transform.rotation);

        Debug.Log(Input.mousePosition.x);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either turn off looping in the particle system or Stop() or Pause() it on Awake() in your script and Play() when clicking the fire button.

Check this page: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.html

The sample that you have provided doesn't take a particle system, but some 'projectile' prefab, it basically spawns the prefab instance when you click mouse button. It is just an example of very very basic shooting mechanic. I believe that naming on that script could have been better. (I believe that this sample was taken from one of Unity's Merry Fragmas videos, they used some kind of particle system in a similar manner, you'll have to configure the particle system to burst a bunch of particles and not loop after that if you want to use it this way)

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your detailed answer.